# Truffle migrate fails with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

When I run "truffle migrate" I wait for few seconds than the geth node fall down and I got this truffle error : **"Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually."**

geth console show something like this:

```
   goroutine 38 [select, 3 minutes]:
    github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc420030b60)

+0x144                         
created by github.com/ethereum/
        /build/ethereum-cdyJWd/
+0x430                         

rax    0x0                     
rbx    0x7f74a38c7700          
rcx    0x7f74a3537428          
rdx    0x6                     
rdi    0x76a                   
rsi    0x76b                   
rbp    0x1121082               
rsp    0x7f74a3500928          
r8     0x7f74a38c8770          
r9     0x7f74a3501700          
r10    0x8                     
r11    0x206                   
r12    0x7f748c0008c0          
r13    0xf1                    
r14    0x11                    
r15    0x0                     
rip    0x7f74a3537428          
rflags 0x206                   
cs     0x33                    
fs     0x0                     
gs     0x0
```

**EDIT:** geth v1.8, sol 0.4.23.

I run geth with this command :

```
geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30304 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8504 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://be6dfb42d374e9262cbb557314eeb60b2531396ed04b10512d03f6108fd99f13585d5efffb5cbc8582dbdfb07af3bf8daabd89d9ec322c6cb86b10fcccfd7468@10.2.1.158:30310' --networkid 1515 -unlock '0x6747efc15a7209763e840c8bbf381b721aeababd' --password node1/password.txt --mine
```

Comment: Can you add more details? version of solidity compiler used, version of geth. What command do you use to launch geth? Did you try deploying your contract in ganache? What is your contract code?

Comment: [geth 1.8, sol 0.4.23] .. what makes geth fall down ? ok truffle doesn't work but what makes the entire node fall down?..

Comment: Data corruption or a hardware problem might cause issues that geth cannot cope with. I'd suggest to try in a different computer and if the problem persist try reporting it to geth developers.

Comment: this happens just to the node related to truffle. ok thanks :)